# How to get an imported object dynamically in js browser modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to get an imported object dynamically (by passing the variable's name). Consider this:

```
import { a } from './mymodule.js';

console.log(window['a']);
```

This will print "undefined". How do I get the variable `a` dynamically?

Comment: remove `window`, so try `console.log(a)`

Comment: I don't think `import { a }` adds the property to the `window`. Try `import { * as module } ...` then you can use `module['a']`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you make that an answer, please?

Comment: @Bergi I don't have any solid evidence behind my suggestion... 

Comment: @evolutionxbox But it's true. Is it enough evidence if I said that? :P `import` cannot create globals, that would run contrary to the entire purpose of modules.

Answer (score 0):

`window.a` will not work for a module script. The imported things of a module script (`<script type="module">` in which you can use `import`) load within their own [scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/), so they are not added as a property of `window`.

See [this small test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-so-67253384?file=index.js)

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question?

Comment: "*In a module, `this` is undefined*" doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question?

Comment: Ok, maybe not *that* evident. Removed the link/image

Answer (score 0):

```
import { a } from './mymodule.js';

if (!window.a) {
   window.a = a
}
```

Afterwards you are able to access `a` directly:

```
a.someMethod()
```

or with the window object:

```
window.a.someMethod()
```

Since you created a global object inside the window object. This module is available now inside all script tags on your page and in other js files.

Comment: But then what's the point of using modules?

Comment: This way your have not to make everything global. Inside of js applications it is not a good practice to use the global window object. But for php/html applications you will need this quite often. But then just for the ready to go libraries. Not for every little modul your library contains of. Modules allow your applications to consist of many files.

Comment: Remove the `if (!window.a) {` though. If you really want to make this available as a global variable, you will want to *always* have it available in regardless what environment (e.g. a page with a `<div id="a">`).